# Sort 1D array in relation to ascending sort of 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays, one is a 2 dimensional array, the other is a single dimensional array. I want to sort the second array in relation with the first array

**Example**

Input
`Long [][] timeArray = {(1,2),(6,8),(3,5)};`
`String [] nameList = {George, Bill, Harry};`

Output
`timeArray = {(1,2),(3,5),(6,8)} //Array sorted in ascending order`
`nameList = {George, Harry, Bill} //Array sorted in relation to timeArray`

I am able to sort the 2D array using

`Arrays.sort(timeArray, Comparator.comparingLong(a -> a[0]));`

but I am not able to figure a way to sort them in relation with each other without using over-complicated code.

Comment: Java has this neat construction called a class that allows you to group things like names and times together in one instance that can be sorted in name order or time order.

Comment: OMG! I just did that. Guess I was looking too hard? [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67410720/7710460)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom comparator which is sorting the nameList but looking at the timeArray:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(nameList);
Comparator relationComparator = (a, b) -> {
  int indexA =list.indexOf(a);
  Int indexB = list.indexOf(b);

  return timeArray[indexA][0] - timeArray[indexB][0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can relate the 2 arrays (names & times) by putting them in a map, something like:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long[]> peopleTimes = new HashMap<>();
        peopleTimes.put("George", new Long[]{1L, 2L});
        peopleTimes.put("Bill", new Long[]{6L, 8L});
        peopleTimes.put("Harry", new Long[]{3L, 5L});

        Map<String, Long[]> sortedByTime = peopleTimes.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> compareTimes(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }

    // You can define your compare logic or use Comparator
    public static int compareTimes(Long[] time1, Long[] time2) {
        if (time1[0] < time2[0]) return -1;
        if (time1[0] > time2[0]) return 1;
        return Long.compare(time1[1], time2[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a way to sort do this myself. I copied the two arrays into an ArrayList of a custom class and then sorted the ArrayList using Comparator. I still think the code is hacky. Open to suggestions/improvements.

```
public class TimeLog{
    long startTime;
    long endTime;
    String name;
    public TimeLog(long startTime, long endTime, String name){
        super();
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In the main/function

```
ArrayList<TimeLog> timeLog = new ArrayList<>(); //Initializing the custom ArrayList

//Adding timeArray and nameList into custom ArrayList
for(int i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
    timeLog.add(new TimeLog(timeArray[i][0], timeArray[i][1], nameList[i]));
}

//Sorting using Array.sort and Comparator comparing start times (lambda function)
timeLog.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(st -> st.startTime));
```